# Query to select the most recent time in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Guys I have this php code to return the current time:

```
$time = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
```

I saw this time to my database using this code :

```
$query = "INSERT into `time` VALUES('', '$time')";
```

And the time row values update every transaction.

The question here is how I could return the most recent time?

I think i need an sql statement that return the time **descendingly** but I don't know what is it, so any help?

Comment: Are you looking for the `ORDER BY` keywords in SQL?

Comment: I know how to order using Id and things like this but I don't know how to `ORDER BY` using time format like mine

Comment: It's exactly the same.  Just specify the column you want to, well, order by.  You should at least *try* first.

Comment: This is why you should not use the format `m/d/Y h:i:s a` and `VARCHAR`. If you used MySQL's `datetime` column format and `Y-m-d h:i:s` this would be a simple task.

Comment: Actually I tried @David but it didn't work because I am not using sql `datetime`

Comment: @Sean you are right but in my case I have to time `m/d/Y h:i:a`

Comment: @AhmedEssam: It seems the simplest approach would be to store the data in the correct format.  If you're using `datetime` data, then store it as `datetime`.  That'll make calculations on the data a *lot* easier.

Comment: @David I will change it and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a simple select, depending on what you want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM time ORDER BY <time> DESC LIMIT 1
```

I don't know the name of the column so I wrote `<time>`.

Comment: wrap you `<time>` with backticks - `\`<time>\``, so that it shows up, as right now you have `...so I wrote`, instead of `so I wrote <time>`.

Comment: The problem is that I am not using sql `timedate` stamp

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do an `ORDER BY` and a `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT  `yourTimeColumn`
FROM    `time`
ORDER BY `yourTimeColumn` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

In addition, you could do your `INSERT` with the current time by just doing:

```
INSERT INTO `time` VALUES ('', NOW())
```

Comment: The problem is that I am not using sql timedate stamp

Answer (score 0):

if your date is not in datetime format then It needs to be converted to datetime first.
Hope the following will help you.

```
SELECT * FROM time ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, column) DESC LIMIT 1
```

column is the name of the time column.